# jquery Stop/Start slider button

Tags: jquery, button, slider

I'm looking solution for a simple task. How to programm button to stop/start a slideshow.
I made startSlider, stopSlider functions and when I save chnges, button disappear.

```
    $('#stopStartBtn').toggle(
        function(e){ e.preventDefault();
            stopSlider()}, 
        function(e){ e.preventDefault();
            startSlider();}
        );
```

Apart form that, slider reacts (stop/start) on hover and starts on document ready.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li class="image" rel="Image 01"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/720x400/000/fff.png" alt="#"></li>
        <li class="image" rel="Image 02"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/720x400/000766/0011ff.png" alt="#"></li>
        <li class="image" rel="Image 03"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/720x400/c9c9c9/0011ff.png" alt="#"></li>
        <li class="image" rel="Image 04"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/720x400/000/fff.png" alt="#"></li>
        <li class="image" rel="Image 05"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/720x400/c9c9c9/0011ff.png" alt="#"></li>
        <li class="image" rel="Image 06"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/720x400/000766/0011ff.png" alt="#"></li>
    </ul><!--./slides-->
</div><!--./slider-->
<button id="stopStartBtn">Stop/Start</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    //configuration
    var width = 720,
        animationSpeed = 1000,
        pause = 500,
        currentImage = 1,
        interval;

    //cache DOM
    var $slider = $('#slider'),
        $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides'),
        $image = $slideContainer.find('.image');

    //setInterval
    function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},animationSpeed, function(){
                currentImage++;
                //if it's last slide go to position 1 (0px)
                if(currentImage === $image.length) {
                    currentImage = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left',0);
                }
            });
        },pause);//setInterval
    }//startSlider

    function stopSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }//stopSlider

    //hover stop/start
    $slider.on('mouseenter',stopSlider).on('mouseleave',startSlider);

    $('#stopStartBtn').toggle(
        function(e){ e.preventDefault();
            stopSlider();}, 
        function(e){ e.preventDefault();
            startSlider();}
        );

    startSlider();
});//ready
```

Comment: do the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events work as expected?

Comment: Yes mouseenter and mousleave works fine without toggle, here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/kuba0506/q13naavj/2/

Answer (score 1):

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Amin52J/q13naavj/3/)**

```
var started=true;
$('#stopStartBtn').click(function(){
    if(started){
        stopSlider();
        started=false;
    }
    else{
        startSlider();
        started=true;
    }
});
```

**Explanation:**

`toggle()` function is to hide or show an element, you can not use it to create a toggle button, what you can do is to simulate the toggle action using a variable as mentioned in the answer code.

Also the `pause` variable must be equal to `animationSpeed` variable.

Comment: That's great! Thx, tell me why variables pause and animationSpeed should be equal?

Comment: because if `pause` is smaller than `animationSpeed`, the slide animations will be queued, therefore the stop action will take not immediately take effect! see it for yourself => http://jsfiddle.net/Amin52J/q13naavj/4/